# How to replace all spaces in a data frame with underscores?

Tags: replaceall

```
Example_df <- tibble(

Site = c("Oyster Bed", "Rock Harbour"),
Species = c("Rhizophora mangle", "Avecinnia germinans"),
Colour = c("Red", "Black"))
```

so i would like to change to this for the whole data set...

```
Example_df <- tibble

(Site = c("Oyster_Bed", "Rock_Harbour"),
Species = c("Rhizophora_mangle", "Avecinnia_germinans"),
Colour = c("Red", "Black"))
```

Replace the spaces with underscores